# Kapt does not work with AutoValue in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, auto-value, kapt

Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

provided "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
```

getting this stacktrace:

```
:presentation:kaptDevDebugKotlin
e: @AutoValue public abstract class Categories implements CategoriesModel{
e:                                                        ^
e:   symbol: class CategoriesModel
e: path/Categories.java:13: error: cannot find symbol

w: warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated]'
w: 


e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:347)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:336)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:387)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:784)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:811)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:783)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:971)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:851)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:777)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:971)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:851)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:327)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor168.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I think Kotlin does not need AutoValue at all because it has data classes https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: try to use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

Comment: @AntonGolovin It is a legacy project.

Comment: @quiro this gives the same output

Comment: Please file the new bug to our issue tracker http://kotl.in/issue. A sample project is also appreciated.

Comment: I remember an issue with it. The resolution was to port all auto-value classes to kotlin data classes at once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Geng Jiawen answer gave right direction, I changed everything to `kapt`

```
provided "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
kapt "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
kaptTest "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
```

But then I was getting

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':presentation:javaPreCompileProdDebug'.
>
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following
>   dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation
>   processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>
> ```
> - auto-value-1.4.1.jar
> - auto-value-gson-0.4.6.jar
> - auto-service-1.0-rc2.jar
> ```
>
> Alternatively, set
>
> `android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions
>   .includeCompileClasspath = true`
>
> to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.   See
>   https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html
>   for more details.

I added

```
defaultConfig {
    javaCompileOptions {
      annotationProcessorOptions {
        includeCompileClasspath false
      }
    }
  }
```

Only then it worked properly.

I want to mention that **using kapt increased build time on 8-10%**

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm concerned about the deprecation warning. Am I setting myself up for disaster in the future?

Comment: `using kapt increased build time on 8-10%` Is there any proof?

Comment: Since provided is now deprecated, using kapt and annotationProcessor in a pair worked for me like so:     annotationProcessor  'com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.7'
    kapt  'com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.7'

Answer (score 4):

I run this problem too. The fix is easy, just change AutoValue annotationProcessor to kapt. Kapt generate java file, not kotlin file from my observation. So the original annotationProcessor is unnecessary. Also remember to clean your project after this change.

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

provided "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
kapt "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
```

Migrate current project to kotlin is not that easy, but let's keep trying it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed the same problem by removing `provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'` from my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig {
javaCompileOptions {
  annotationProcessorOptions {
    includeCompileClasspath true
  }
}
```

}
in module build gradle